# How to create Active Directory users and put them under Organization Unit using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have OUs that have the following form:

```
Accounts
   |->Normal
        |->100
            |->A
            |->B
        |->101
            |->A
            |->B
```

And so on with more OUs. What I want to do is I want to bulk create users under each A and B OU. In each A and B, I want to have 10 users. And I want their name to have the following form: `Account-100-A-01`, `Account-100-A-02`, and so on. Basically, the word `Account` followed by the OU number which can be from 100 to 200 in my case, then the OU under that which is either A or B, and then the account number which will be from 01 to 10.

I know the `New-ADUser` command, but I don't know what's the best way to achieve this bulk creation in my case. Like forming the usernames that correspond to naming convention that I want, and to actually put the users to their corresponding OUs. Any ideas?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$count = 1
for ($i=100; $i -lt 200; $i++) 
{ 
 $label = "A"
 for ($j=0; $j -lt 20; $j++)
 {
   if($j -ge 10) $label = "B"

   $username = "Account-$i-$label-(($j%10)+1)"
   Write-Host "Creating AD user " $count++ ": " $username

   New-ADUser `
     -Name $username `
     -AccountExpirationDate 0 `
     -PasswordNeverExpires $true`
     -SamAccountName $username `
     -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword123" -AsPlainText -Force) `
     -Enabled $true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like...:

```
[Int32]    $Local:intOUIndex   = 0;
[String[]] $Local:arrSubOUs    = @( 'A', 'B' );
[Int32]    $Local:intUserIndex = 0;
[String]   $Local:strSubOU     = '';
[String]   $Local:strOUDN      = '';
[String]   $Local:strUserCN    = '';

for ( $intOUIndex = 100; $intOUIndex -le 200; $intOUIndex++ ) {
    foreach ( $strSubOU in $arrSubOUs ) {
        $strOUDN = 'OU={0},OU={1:000},OU=Normal,OU=Accounts,DC=yourdomain,DC=com' -f $strSubOU, $intOUIndex;
        for ( $intUserIndex = 1; $intUserIndex -le 10; $intUserIndex++ ) {
            $strUserCN = 'Account-{0:000}-{1}-{2:00}' -f $intOUIndex, $strSubOU, $intUserIndex;

            Write-Host -Object ( 'Creating account "{0}" in OU "{1}"...' -f $strUserCN, $strOUDN );

            # Call New-ADUser, e.g.:

            New-ADUser -Name $strUserCN -Path $strOUDN (Etc.)

            } #for-userindex
        } #foreach-subou
    } #for-intOUIndex
```

Comment: Thanks, and is there a way to specify also in which groups the user should be member?

Comment: Use `Add-ADGroupMember`